# Emacs - Can't get Flymake to work with JSHint

Tags: emacs, flymake, jshint

I'm trying to get JSHint to work with Flymake.

`jshint` is indeed installed in `/opt/bin` and works. `/opt/bin` is in Emacs' `exec-path`.

I've followed [the directions on the EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FlymakeJavaScript) and have this in my `init.el`:

```
(defun flymake-jshint-init ()
  (let* ((temp-file (flymake-init-create-temp-buffer-copy
                     'flymake-create-temp-inplace))
         (local-file (file-relative-name
                      temp-file
                      (file-name-directory buffer-file-name))))
    (list "jshint" (list local-file))))

(setq flymake-err-line-patterns
      (cons '("^  [[:digit:]]+ \\([[:digit:]]+\\),\\([[:digit:]]+\\): \\(.+\\)$"
              nil 1 2 3)
            flymake-err-line-patterns))

(add-to-list 'flymake-allowed-file-name-masks
             '("\\.js\\'" flymake-jshint-init))
```

When I open JavaScript files, my modeline appears as:

```
[(Javascript Flymake* AC)]
```

This is odd because the `*` usually doesn't appear when I'm using Flymake with C++ or Python. According to the Flymake docs, `Flymake*` means "Flymake is currently running." However, Flymake isn't showing any errors.

I've checked the `*Messages*` buffer but it only lists a few lines of `Fontifying foo.js... (regexps...................)`. No errors.

Other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a project called [jshint-mode](https://github.com/daleharvey/jshint-mode) and tried that. It created a buffer called `*jshint-mode*` which revealed the error: JSHint couldn't find the formidable module.

I ran <kbd>M-x setenv</kbd> in Emacs to set `NODE_PATH` so that `jshint` could find the formidable library. I also set `NODE_PATH` in `/etc/profile`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `M-:` to execute `(setq flymake-log-level 3)`, which will cause flymake to print debug info into `*Messages*`.

[Here's how I use flymake with jslint](https://github.com/purcell/flymake-jslint/blob/master/flymake-jslint.el), which works nicely for me -- that code might give you a clue about what's going wrong for you.

You might also consider `js2-mode`, which provides some language-aware lint-like warnings without resorting to running an external process.

Answer (score 0):

[jshint-mode](https://github.com/daleharvey/jshint-mode) did not work for me (I use Linux Mint 14 'Nadia') -- I was getting errors with "flymake's configuration" when it runs `curl` to talk to the Node.js instance running the jshint script. This was perplexing, and I'm not familiar with ELisp to go around messing with the `.el` files.

I solved this by instead going straight to the Emacs [flymake project](https://github.com/illusori/emacs-flymake) fork on github which now has support for jshint built-in (it needs to be installed as `npm -g install jshint` which in turn requires you to install `npm` and node.js if you haven't already). This made things work.

One more caveat: on my Linux box, `node` was an executable already existing in `/usr/sbin` and I had to make a symbolic link named `node` in `/usr/local/bin` to override the former. This was necessary as the Node.js binary for Linux Mint (possibly Ubuntu as well, I haven't checked) is named `nodejs` instead and will cause many scripts written assuming a binary name of `node` to fail. You can test this by typing `node`: if it is the pre-existing binary it generally returns to the prompt silently, but if it is Node.js it prompts you with a `>` (you can Ctrl-D to quit out of there)